# Покрытие кода Cmake

Tags: c++, консоль, cmake

Как совместить Cmake и отчёт о покрытии кода?

В терминале можно сделать так:

```
g++ --coverage main.cpp -o main
./main
lcov -t "main" -o main.info -c -d .
genhtml -o report main.info
```

Хотелось бы первую строчку: `g++ --coverage main.cpp -o main`. Сделать в Cmake.
Просто не понятно как указать флаг компиляции --coverage в Cmake.
Мы же просто пишем `add_executable(main main.cpp)` и тут флаг указать нельзя.
Пробовал `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -O0 --coverage")`, но не помогает.

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html#command:target_compile_options *"Мы же просто пишем"* - в реальных сценариях такое не прокатывает